# 'children' is not defined in React

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I get the error 'children' is not defined in React when I am creating a context to use in the entire App.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

const allContexts = React.createContext();

export function AllContexts(){
    var prueba = [{test: 'funciona'}]

    return (
        <allContexts.Provider value={prueba}>
            {children}
        </allContexts.Provider>
    )

}
```

Then I add the componen in my file App.js so I can access the info from the component, but it errors because of the children.
Do you know what I´m doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to declare the props in your component. For example:

```
export function AllContexts({children}:props){
    var prueba = [{test: 'funciona'}]

    return (
        <allContexts.Provider value={prueba}>
            {children}
        </allContexts.Provider>
    )

}
```

Then you can add this component in your App.js and insert jsx code inside.